# post deployment script to run a script only one time

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools

If I want to have the post deployment script run a script only one time is there a way to do this?

I want to run post deployment scripts only once for my database

Comment: Why would it be ran more than once?  If you only want to run it once, only run it once.

Comment: Because if you have post script in the project it automatically executes every time you publish the project if only you did something to prevent that.

Answer (score 9):

When working with one-time scripts, you can use the `Script.PostDeployment.sql` and `Script.PreDeployment.sql` files to execute the scripts before and after deployment respectively. To keep track of which scripts have been executed, you can create a history table to record the script name, the database name, and the execution time.

In your `Script.PostDeployment.sql` file, you can use the following code to execute the one-time script:

```
:SETVAR ScriptNameId ".\PostScripts\PathToScript\ScriptNameHere"
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (   SELECT *
                    FROM dbo.ScriptsHistoryTableWithVeryNiceName
                   WHERE Script_Name_Id = '$(ScriptNameId)' AND database_name = DB_NAME())
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            :r $(ScriptNameId)".SQL"
            INSERT INTO dbo.ScriptsHistoryTableWithVeryNiceName
            VALUES ('$(ScriptNameId)', DB_NAME(), SYSDATETIME());
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            DECLARE @err VARCHAR(MAX) = ERROR_MESSAGE();

            RAISERROR('One time script $(ScriptNameId).sql failed %s', 16, 1, @err);
        END CATCH;
    END;
GO
```

In this code, you can specify the path to the one-time script by setting the `ScriptNameId` variable. If the script has not been executed before, the script file will be executed, and its details will be added to the history table.

Here's the code to create the `dbo.ScriptsHistoryTableWithVeryNiceName` table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ScriptsHistoryTableWithVeryNiceName
(
    ScriptNameId  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
  , DatabaseName  sysname NOT NULL
  , ExecutionTime DATETIME2(7) NOT NULL
);
GO
```

**IMPORTANT**: you cannot include a `GO` statement within the one-time script file itself, as this will cause the outer script to be prematurely terminated.

Answer (score 5):

The best approach I have found to this is to make sure your scripts are re-runnable or idempotent (for the long winded).

So, if you want to do something like insert a row, check whether it exists first.

If you want to setup a reference data or static data table, use merge statements.

If you want to rebuild an index, use sys.stats to check the date of the last rebuild.

ed

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do that is using a SQLCMD variable in a conditional statement. Supposing to set the SQLCMD variable "IsTheFirstDeployment" to "1" in the Project properties, you can use something like this in the post-deployment scripts:

```
IF '$(IsTheFirstDeployment)' = '1'
BEGIN

...your code...

END
```

Comment: There are about 250+ post deployment scripts in my database. Is there any another solution rather than CMD variable.

Comment: Sumit, with that many, you may want to start consolidating and/or removing scripts that are no longer needed. There are also ways to manipulate the build process to exclude those files, but that can get tricky (I've seen it - haven't done it).   You may also consider versioning your dacpacs so v1 scripts are in dacpac_v1, etc. Then remove those from future versions. Can incrementally build through those to build up the scripts if necessary.